# Cube is a rectangular Prism

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I am attempting to make a cube in OpenGL ES 2 using iOS. Despite transforming my drawing it is a rectangular prism instead of a square. I've looked at documentation for hours and I just can't figure out why it is a rectangular prism instead of a cube.

Because there is a fair amount of code with the shaders included, I've posted the entire project for download. If anyone could help me make my rectangular prism a cube I would be very appreciative.

Here is the download link:

https://copy.com/rk3jIGsIkzM2

Any help is very appreciated!

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you're having a problem here. I ran the app in the simulator, and saw that the block was rendered in perspective, albeit with a few lines missing.  I'd suggest adding some code so that swipes or touches change the perspective, to see if it looks like a square once you've maneuvered it so that each face is square to the viewer.

You'll make progress faster if you can interact with app instead of having to go through the compile-link-simulate cycle for every parameter change you want to evaluate.

Comment: Thanks for the response! Regardless of the perspective though, shouldn't the cube still be a cube shape rather than a prism? If I rotate a cube in real life it stays as a cube and doesn't turn into a rectangular prism. I may be mistaken though. Thanks again, I was worrying that no one knew how to fix it.

Comment: "_The reason for this, is that the human eye is not used to seeing orthographic projections._". 

Taken from [here](https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/133666-My-cube-is-not-a-cube)